# Arch Linux not displaying most characters

Tags: arch-linux, gui

My completely up-to-date Arch Linux install has suddenly began to show only a few characters of text. From what I can tell the visible characters are g, x, v, f, m, n, d, U, 0,W, \, and |. All other characters seem to occupy space but are blank. Any help is appreciated.

[image].

Comment: Thanks for that @muru, I posted on mobile and couldn't work out how to embed the image.

Comment: I've seen that on arch once before, but at the time I accused the outdated hardware (it was only present on that computer - maybe a problem with video driver that caches/renders fonts). However it may not be the case... I'm interested in what actually causes this.

Comment: I've seen that with buggy video drivers. (Buggy video drivers cause the strangest bugs sometimes.) What graphics card do you have, and what video driver do you use? Does it work if you start another X server? If you reboot?